# Use of $ in postfix expression

Tags: data-structures, rpn

1. The value of the postfix expression `8 3 4 + - 3 8 2 / + * 2 $ 3 +` is:

   a) 17

   b) 131

   c) 64

   d) 52
2. Prefix of `A-B/C*D$E` is:

   a)`-/*$ACBDE`

   b)`-ABCD*$DE`

   c)`-A/B*C*$DE`

   d)`-A/BC*$DE`

Can anybody explain to me how to solve these expressions when a `$` sign is present? What does this dollar sign indicate?

Comment: The meaning of the `$` symbol should have been clearly explained by whoever is asking the questions, or the material(s) and/or subject(s) they are referring to. Without the context, I'm not sure what it means.

Comment: What's your book say? I'm not familiar with the use of `$` in reverse-polish notation.

Comment: I've seen $ used as exponentiation operator and as an exit marker

Comment: You can solve the second question without knowing what the `$` operator means.

Comment: Actually I came across the first question in this year's ugc net cs paper and the second one from an exercise given in a work book.No other details were mentioned,only the question and its probable answers were given.I was just practicing problems from these two sources and is not a homework given to me by any teacher.In one of the books it was mentioned as a delimiter/exit marker and nothing more than that.I couldn't understand how to deal with that $ sign.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, I am certain the operator is *exponentiation*.

```
  8 3 4 + - 3 8 2 / + * 2 $ 3 + is:

  8 3 4 + - = 1

  3 8 2 / + = 7

  1 7 * = 7

  7 2 $ = 49

  49 3 + = 52.
```

Or maybe

```
  7 2 $ = 128

  128 3 + = 131.
```

Depends on how your instructor defined the operator.

Comment: If `$` were exponentiation, wouldn't `7 2 $` mean 7^2, or 49? Then `49 3 +` would be 52.

Comment: Thanks to all who have tried to help me out by answering the problem.If you have any other idea then please share it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, dollar operator is called exponentiation operator. Means if i say A$B so it means B in the power of A. Ex. 3$2=3*3=9.

```
             Also this exponentiation operator has highest precedence among all operators.
```

:Precedence.
    EXPONENTIATION($)
    MULTIPLICATION/DIVISION
    ADDITION/SUBTRACTION.

So in above given two questions correct answer is 
1. 131
2. -/*$ABCDE

Best of Luck.  :)